# Convert list of Tuples into Dictionary(All tuples convert seperate dictionary)

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have to convert list of tuples into seperate dictionaries. I have tried, But I don't get I wanted.
my list,

```
[('AF', 'Afghanistan'), ('AX', 'Åland Islands'), ('AL', 'Albania'), ('DZ', 'Algeria'), ('AS', 'American Samoa'), ('AD', 'Andorra'), ('AO', 'Angola'), ('AI', 'Anguilla'), ('AQ', 'Antarctica')]
```

what I want,

```
 {
        "countries": [{
            "code": "AF",
            "name": "Afghanistan"
        },
 
      {
            "code": "AX",
            "name": "Åland Islands"
        },
       {
            "code": "AL",
            "name": "Albania"
    }]
}
```

Anyhelp Appreciable,..

Comment: Is there a reason you're only taking the first 3 entries, or is that just a sample?

Comment: Why would you want that result?  That's about the least convenient format for the data imaginable.  A *single* dictionary, like `{'AF': 'Afghanistan, 'AX': 'Åland Islands', 'AL': 'Albania'}` would let you directly look up the country name given a code, rather than having to iterate through the entire list each time.

Comment: Check out what this gives you : `dict([('AF', 'Afghanistan')])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use list comprehension like so:

```
countries = [('AF', 'Afghanistan'), ('AX', 'Åland Islands'), ('AL', 'Albania'), ('DZ', 'Algeria'), ('AS', 'American Samoa'), ('AD', 'Andorra'), ('AO', 'Angola'), ('AI', 'Anguilla'), ('AQ', 'Antarctica')]
output = {"countries": [{"code": code, "name": name} for code, name in countries]}
```

Answer (score 0):

how about

```
countries = {"countries": [{"code":key, "name":value} for (key, value) in tuples]}`
```